# Remove a string from a text file

Tags: unix, vim, awk, sed

I have a very large text file made up of 10000s of lines, like so:

```
Contig9 Pfam    protein_match   57  81  1.9E-6  +   .   Name=PF12874;Note=Zinc-finger of C2H2 type;Target=null 57 81;status=T;ID=match$554_57_81;date=10-10-2014
Contig9 SMART   protein_match   54  88  9.4E-9  +   .   Name=SM00451;Note=U1-like zinc finger;Target=null 54 88;status=T;ID=match$555_54_88;Ontology_term="GO:0003676"
```

I would like to remove the part with `;ID=matchXXXXX` from all lines.

Would there be an easy way to do so using VIM awk or sed in unix?

Comment: The string to be removed ends before the next ';'?

Comment: Yes, I wish to remove all strings that are similar to this format ;ID=XXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Ok, but until the end of line, or util the first ';' charater?

Comment: Apologies, until the next ';' character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
awk '{sub(";ID=match[^;]+","")}1' input_file
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `:%s` command:

```
:%s/ID=match.\{-};//g
```

This removes all occurrences of `ID=match` followed by any characters (`\{-}` to make it non greedy) followed by a `;` with nothing (removing it).

After executing you get

```
Contig9 SMART protein_match 54 88 9.4E-9 + . Name=SM00451;Note=U1-like zinc finger;Target=null 54 88;status=T;Ontology_term="GO:0003676"
```

instead of

```
Contig9 SMART protein_match 54 88 9.4E-9 + . Name=SM00451;Note=U1-like zinc finger;Target=null 54 88;status=T;ID=match$555_54_88;Ontology_term="GO:0003676"
```

Notice the `ID=match$555_54_88;` has been removed

Comment: `.*` is greedy! So if there is two ';' in the line, then it will gobbles up until the second one...

Comment: The regex is no longer greedy thanks to `.\{-}` instead of `.*`. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's/ID=match.*;//' file.txt
```

Comment: +1 for inplace file modification! I think `g` is not needed, but it is not clear from the question. .*` is greedy, so it will gobble everything up to the last `;` char.

Comment: Yeah you're right about the `g`, with the `.*` being greedy I'm relying on it being the last possible match.